# Scroll for all records ElasticSearch C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Query to scroll at the matching records from the query

this is the query of nest in C# to get all the records from nest C# find many questions which can solve it by using different method linq method but i want to do this this way any suggestions help would be appreciated

```
string[] MERCHANTNO = MerchantId.Split(",");
var mustClause = new List<QueryContainer>();
var filterClause = new List<QueryContainer>();
var filters = new List<QueryContainer>();
filters.Add(new TermsQuery{
    Field = new Field("MERCHANTNO"),
    Terms = MERCHANTNO,
});

Logger.LogInformation(clsName, funcName, "Filter Clause is:", filters);

var SearchRequest = new SearchRequest<AcquirerDTO>(idxName) {
    Size       = 10000,
    SearchType = Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.QueryThenFetch,
    Scroll     = "5m",
    Query = new BoolQuery { Must = filters }
};

var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<AcquirerDTO>( SearchRequest );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll" and "nest"? To scroll is a UX/UI term, not a database or search-technology term.

Comment: i want to scroll it or in any other way get more than 10,000 records which exceeds the size

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to _page_ results: read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

Comment: If you want to use Linq to build an ElasticSearch query, use ElasticLinq: https://github.com/ElasticLINQ/ElasticLINQ - but personally I'd stick with the stock ElasticSearch library, I'm wary of unnecessary abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for Scroll all the Records you have in ElasticSearch is

Filter

```
  filters.Add(new TermsQuery {
                        Field = new Field("MERCHANTNO"),       >>> Value needs to be searched
                        Terms = MERCHANTNO,
                    });
```

Date Range Filter

```
                filterClause.Add(new DateRangeQuery {
                    Boost = 1.1,
                    Field = new Field("filedate"),
                    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(yesterday),
                    LessThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(Today),
                    Format = "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    TimeZone = "+01:00"
                });
```

Search Request for scrolling

```
                var SearchRequest = new SearchRequest<AcquirerDTO>(idxName) {
                    From = 0,
                    Scroll = scrollTimeoutMinutes,
                    Size = scrollPageSize,
                    Query = new BoolQuery
                    {
                        Must = filters,
                        Filter = filterClause
                    }
                };
                var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<AcquirerDTO>(SearchRequest);

                if (searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes != null) {
                    var requestJson = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
                    var JsonFormatQuery = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestJson), Formatting.Indented);
                    
                }
```

This is the code for Scrolling all the results in kibana

```
       List<AcquirerDTO> results = new List<AcquirerDTO>();
                if (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                    results.AddRange(searchResponse.Documents);

                string scrollid = searchResponse.ScrollId;
                bool isScrollSetHasData = true;

                while (isScrollSetHasData)
                {
                    ISearchResponse<AcquirerDTO> loopingResponse = _elasticClient.Scroll<AcquirerDTO>(scrollTimeoutMinutes, scrollid);
                    if (loopingResponse.IsValid)
                    {
                        results.AddRange(loopingResponse.Documents);
                        scrollid = loopingResponse.ScrollId;
                    }
                    isScrollSetHasData = loopingResponse.Documents.Any();
                }
                var records = results;
```